# javascript | match alphanumeric or numeric string

Tags: javascript, regex, match

I'm trying to detect string variants: `{ext_1}` or `{ext_1alpha}` or `{ext_aplpha1}`
My regular expression: `/{ext_(^[0-9,a-z]+$)}/gi`

```
var arr = str.match(/{ext_(^[0-9,a-z]+$)}/gi);
```

But this is wrong. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have [anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) (`^` and `$`) in the middle of the regex where they can't ever match.

Use

```
/\{ext_([A-Z0-9]+)\}/gi
```

You also don't want a comma in your character class, unless you want to match actual comma characters in your string. Also, it's a good idea to escape curly braces because they can have special meaning in a regex.

Comment: Notably, the curly brackets also needed escaping, as shown in your changed regex. :)

Comment: @UweB: Not really; they only need to be escaped where they could be misinterpreted (which is not the case here). But it's still good practice to do so.

Comment: Doesn't work. This expression can detect only numbers: /{ext_(\d+)}/gi b and it works but my string can contains numbers or alphanumbers...

Comment: @virtualnobi: Oops. Where did that come from? Thanks for noticing this.

Answer (score 1):

This works-

```
/{ext_([a-z0-9]+)}/gi
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
/{ext_([[:alnum:]]+)}/
```

[see here](http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/3C1)